# Using systems calls (open, read, write) to display file content

Tags: c, system-calls, cat

I'm trying to implement a command called displaycontent that takes a text file name as argument and display its contents. I am to use `open()`, `read()`, `write()`, and `close()` system calls in Linux to do this. It should act somewhat like the UNIX `cat` command for displaying file content.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    char content[fd];   

    errno = 0;
    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);


    if(fd < 0)
    {
        printf("File could not be opened.\n");
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }
    else 
    {

        read(fd, content, sizeof(content)-1);
        write(1, content, sizeof(content)-1);
    }

return 0;
}
```

I have a file named hello2.txt and in it, there's the text: `hellooooooooooooooo`

When I do `./displaycontent hello2.txt`, I get:

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/Csc332/csc332lab$ ./displaycontent hello2.txt
hellooooooooooooooo
����>k���[`�s�b��user@user-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/Csc332/csc332lab$
```

There are strange symbols and things following the content of the file. I am not sure what is wrong, any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `char content[fd];` What?

Comment: @devbrs, it looks like you forgot to use `close()`.

Comment: @donjuedo: file-handles are automatically closed on program termination.

Comment: Thank you user3121023 !!

Comment: @EOF, true, but he did say his assignment is to use all 4 functions.

Comment: You cannot call perror after you call printf.  If open fails and sets errno, you need to call perror before you call anything that may change errno.  printf may change errno, making your call to perror produce meaningless output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> use `bytes = read (fd,content,sizeof(content)-1);` to capture the number
>   of bytes read. Then use bytes in `write(1,content,bytes);` to only write
>   the bytes that were read. –  user3121023

Comment: And `bytes` should be of type `ssize_t`.

Answer (score 5):

`fd` is not initialized, so the size of `content` is not determined.

You should not use the fd for that, anyway.  You could use a large fixed number, if this is just an exercise.  Otherwise, you'd want to get the file size and use that.

To get the file length, you can follow this example:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main()
{
    int fd = open( "testfile.txt", O_RDONLY );
    if ( fd < 0 )
        return 1;

    off_t fileLength = lseek( fd, 0, SEEK_END );  // goes to end of file
    if ( fileLength < 0 )
        return 1;

    //  Use lseek() again (with SEEK_SET) to go to beginning for read() call to follow.
    close( fd );
    return 0;
}
```

(I have not compiled this today, and am only going from memory.  If there are typos, they should be minor)

Comment: Even if that is fixed there is likely to still be junk output. The `write` outputs the whole buffer rather than just what was read.

Comment: You're right.  I was adding to my answer as you commented.  :-)